# Maps not rendering in Firefox and Safari on MacBook Pro 15" early 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, gpu, firefox

I have a MacBook Pro 15" early 2011 running macOS Catalina with dosdude1's Catalina patcher. The dedicated GPU is inactivated with the non-permanent solution circulating elsewhere.

Ever since I upgraded (perhaps already in Mojave, but not sure about that) I'm unable to use Google Maps and most other map services in Firefox and Safari. In Google Maps, the map view renders correctly, but I'm unable to click any points of interest, and if I move around the map it lags heavily and soon turns black; basically unusable.

However, in Opera Google Maps works perfectly fine! The computer does heat up and the fans start spinning, but at least Google Maps is fully functional and runs smoothly. Apple's own Maps app also runs without any trouble at all.

I also have two MacBook Pro 13" mid-2012 also running Catalina (officially supported), where Google Maps works perfectly fine on both Firefox and Safari, so it doesn't seem to be due to lacking browser support.

Any idea what could be causing this? I assume the inactivated GPU may have something to do with it, but why does it work fine in Opera?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess it's trying to render using hardware acceleration. As you don't have a Metal2 graphics chip, I doubt you'll get it to work unless you can disable that.

As of Catalina this is no longer possible in Safari [as all supported hardware is capable.]

On Chrome it's in Settings > Advanced > System

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the reason, since I have hardware acceleration inactivated also in Firefox.

Comment: It's going to be some kind of incompatibility somewhere - you're warned when trying to go beyond High Sierra without Metal2 hardware. It might be WebGL, also hardwired in Safari, idk about Chrome or FF.

Comment: Ok, nothing I can do about it then. Thanks! Since I haven't found anyone else reporting this from my online searching, I was hoping it might be some local configuration.